# While connecting to Mysql Getting below error with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'Renci.SshNet, Version=2016.1.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1cee9f8bde3db106' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Comment: How are you connecting to mysql?  What command are you trying?  Please [edit] your question with this information.

Comment: $Connection = [MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection]@{ConnectionString='SConnectionString'}
$Connection.ConnectionString = $ConnectionString
$Connection.Open()

Comment: edit the question!